# Update AKS cluster with new server prinicipal credentials

Tags: azure, github-actions, azure-aks, service-principal, azure-service-principal

I am trying to update my  credentials for my AKS cluster because I have moved it to a different tenant. My github workflows automatically push to the cluster but because I moved it to a new tenant my github workflows give me a "ExpiredServicePrincipal" error and now longer work.

After doing some research I found the following link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/update-credentials#update-aks-cluster-with-new-service-principal-credentials which tells me how to update my credentials and then update the AKS cluster with these credentials.

> az aks update-credentials 
> --resource-group myResourceGroup 
> --name myAKSCluster 
> --reset-service-principal 
> --service-principal $SP_ID 
> --client-secret $SP_SECRET

After following this step of the guide I get an error that I can't seem to understand or find any info for online...

> ValidationError: Deployment failed. Correlation ID: ###########. Code="OperationNotAllowed" Message="Operation could not be completed as it results in exceeding approved standardDSv3Family Cores quota. Additional details - Deployment Model: Resource Manager, Location: CanadaCentral, Current Limit: 10, Current Usage: 8, Additional Required: 8, (Minimum) New Limit Required: 16. Submit a request for Quota increase at https://aka.ms/ProdportalCRP/?#create/Microsoft.Support/Parameters/%!B(MISSING)%!s(MISSING)ubId%!:(MISSING)%!c(MISSING)############%!,(MISSING)%!p(MISSING)esId%!:(MISSING)%!b(MISSING)############%!,(MISSING)%!s(MISSING)upportTopicId%!:(MISSING)%!e(MISSING)############%7D by specifying parameters listed in the ‘Details’ section for deployment to succeed. Please read more about quota limits at [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-supportability/per-vm-quota-requests."](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-supportability/per-vm-quota-requests.%22)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/kubernetes-action
I appreciate any help at all! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

It appears you are exceeding your CanadaCentral Regional vCPUs limit and need to request more quota for the DSv3Family.  There is no charge for increasing quota, only for the cores that are used.  Just follow the link in the error message to open a support case.  Most times quota requests are approved automatically within a couple mins.

Resource Manager vCPU quotas for virtual machines and virtual machine scale sets are enforced at two tiers for each subscription, in each region.

The first tier is the Total Regional vCPUs limit across all VM series. The second tier is the per VM series vCPUs limit, such as the D-series vCPUs. Anytime a new virtual machine is to be deployed, the sum of new and existing vCPUs usage for that VM series must not exceed the vCPU quota approved for that particular VM series. Further, the total new and existing vCPU count deployed across all VM series shouldn't exceed the Total Regional vCPUs quota approved for the subscription. If either of those quotas are exceeded, the VM deployment won't be allowed. You can request an increase of the vCPUs quota limit for the VM series from Azure portal. An increase in the VM series quota automatically increases the Total Regional vCPUs limit by the same amount.

When a new subscription is created, the default Total Regional vCPUs may not be equal to the sum of default vCPU quotas for all individual VM series. This fact can result in a subscription with enough quota for each individual VM series that you want to deploy. It could lack enough quota for Total Regional vCPUs for all deployments. In this case, you'll need to submit a request to increase the Total Regional vCPUs limit explicitly. Total Regional vCPUs limit can't exceed the sum of approved quota across all VM series for the region.